# Get current Sub name for a VB-script

Tags: vbscript, testcomplete

I am developing VBscript for GUI testing. And I wonder if there is possibilites to get the current Sub name.

I have divied the GUI testing into different Sub and want to log the Sub name to the logg file to track what is run.

So this i that I want

```
Sub TestCase1
 Log.Message(SubName)

 ' Rest of test
End Sub
```

By using this I don't have the sub name hardcoded as a text string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript (unlike JScript) doesn't provide any means to get the current routine name.

What you need is to run your script routines as  [test items](http://www.automatedqa.com/support/viewarticle.aspx?aid=2628) (you're using TestComplete, right?) — in this case you'll get a tree-like log with messages grouped by script routines.
You'll also be able to access the test items programmatically via the [`Project.TestItems`](http://www.automatedqa.com/support/viewarticle.aspx?aid=4939) object. For example, you'll be able to get the name of the current script routine that is run as a test item using the [`Project.TestItems.Current.ElementToBeRun.Caption`](http://www.automatedqa.com/support/viewarticle.aspx?aid=6800) property.

Comment: Okay. 

Thanks for the replay. If VBScript can not handle it there is nothing to do. Then it will be a static string. Because I want the name of each Sub. And Project.TestItems is just related to the Test one defines and I want to log several sub calls in a test.